# Monitoring the FileSystem ( file creation ) with a Phoenix App

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

Within a Phoenix App, I need to trigger a task when a file is created server side in a specific folder.

I looked into the two solutions :

- https://fs.n2o.space/
- https://github.com/falood/file_system

Are those the right kind of tools for the job? I'm really new to this stack.

Thanks

Comment: phoenix uses inotify for auto-recompiling on code change, I think that is a good starting point

Comment: Ok, so you advise using inotify directly. Not supported wrapper are around? I'm fine with that, I would rather not re-invent the wheel.

Comment: looks like they are using file_system for reloading, so it seems your first choice was correct.